# Buildbot "First Run" doesn't work for me. How do I diagnose it?

Tags: buildbot

So even the most basic buildbot tutorial (http://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html) has failed for me.

OS: Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon 64-bit

Cinnamon Version: 2.4.8

Linux Kernel: 3.13.0-37-generic

```
~/tmp $ cd
~ $ mkdir -p tmp/buildbot
~ $ cd tmp/buildbot
~/tmp/buildbot $ virtualenv --no-site-packages sandbox
New python executable in sandbox/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
~/tmp/buildbot $ source sandbox/bin/activate
(sandbox)~/tmp/buildbot $ easy_install sqlalchemy==0.7.10
Searching for sqlalchemy==0.7.10
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/sqlalchemy/
Best match: SQLAlchemy 0.7.10
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/SQLAlchemy/SQLAlchemy-0.7.10.tar.gz#md5=ecc0cd1cd906d17818a5f08fe13ae19e
Processing SQLAlchemy-0.7.10.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-_Q_iMm/SQLAlchemy-0.7.10/setup.cfg
Running SQLAlchemy-0.7.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-_Q_iMm/SQLAlchemy-0.7.10/egg-dist-tmp-s3psrw
warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'doc'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build/output'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding SQLAlchemy 0.7.10 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.10-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for sqlalchemy==0.7.10
Finished processing dependencies for sqlalchemy==0.7.10
(sandbox)~/tmp/buildbot $ easy_install buildbot
Searching for buildbot
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/buildbot/
Best match: buildbot 0.9.0b2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/buildbot/buildbot-0.9.0b2.tar.gz#md5=69d75a4e2c5db5b1e0ebab23476f0897
Processing buildbot-0.9.0b2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-5UymBr/buildbot-0.9.0b2/setup.cfg
Running buildbot-0.9.0b2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-5UymBr/buildbot-0.9.0b2/egg-dist-tmp-ZvVxCY
warning: no files found matching 'buildbot/clients/debug.glade'
warning: no files found matching 'master/buildbot/www/index.html'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
buildbot.config: module references __file__
buildbot.__init__: module references __file__
buildbot.db.model: module references __file__
buildbot.reporters.message: module references __file__
buildbot.process.buildstep: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
buildbot.scripts.create_master: module references __file__
buildbot.scripts.upgrade_master: module references __file__
buildbot.scripts.base: module references __file__
buildbot.test.integration.test_configs: module references __file__
buildbot.test.integration.test_upgrade: module references __file__
buildbot.test.unit.test_www_config: module references __file__
/home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py:440: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  symbols = dict.fromkeys(iter_symbols(code))
buildbot.test.unit.test_contrib_buildbot_cvs_mail: module references __file__
buildbot.test.unit.test_steps_transfer: module references __file__
Adding buildbot 0.9.0b2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing buildbot script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildbot-0.9.0b2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for buildbot
Searching for autobahn>=0.10.2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/autobahn/
Best match: autobahn 0.10.9
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/autobahn/autobahn-0.10.9.tar.gz#md5=fa90fa91f9c0e711ca6e87c7e9d835b7
Processing autobahn-0.10.9.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-cjVD0z/autobahn-0.10.9/setup.cfg
Running autobahn-0.10.9/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-cjVD0z/autobahn-0.10.9/egg-dist-tmp-gvenDF
package init file 'twisted/plugins/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
Adding autobahn 0.10.9 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autobahn-0.10.9-py2.7.egg
Searching for python-dateutil>=1.5
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-dateutil/
Reading http://labix.org/python-dateutil
Reading https://dateutil.readthedocs.org
Best match: python-dateutil 2.4.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-dateutil/python-dateutil-2.4.2.tar.gz#md5=4ef68e1c485b09e9f034e10473e5add2
Processing python-dateutil-2.4.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-kNEDZF/python-dateutil-2.4.2/setup.cfg
Running python-dateutil-2.4.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-kNEDZF/python-dateutil-2.4.2/egg-dist-tmp-Oay0AQ
Adding python-dateutil 2.4.2 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7.egg
Searching for sqlalchemy-migrate==0.7.2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/sqlalchemy-migrate/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/
Reading http://erosson.com/migrate
Reading http://trac.erosson.com/migrate
Reading http://www.openstack.org/
Best match: sqlalchemy-migrate 0.7.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/sqlalchemy-migrate/sqlalchemy-migrate-0.7.2.tar.gz#md5=10382fda16f056491e671b5307dd6713
Processing sqlalchemy-migrate-0.7.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-TpMB8k/sqlalchemy-migrate-0.7.2/setup.cfg
Running sqlalchemy-migrate-0.7.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-TpMB8k/sqlalchemy-migrate-0.7.2/egg-dist-tmp-cZ2EJX
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hgtags'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
migrate.tests.__init__: module references __file__
migrate.tests.integrated.test_docs: module references __file__
migrate.tests.versioning.test_template: module references __path__
migrate.versioning.api: module MAY be using inspect.getsource
Adding sqlalchemy-migrate 0.7.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing migrate script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing migrate-repository script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy_migrate-0.7.2-py2.7.egg
Searching for future
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/future/
Best match: future 0.15.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/f/future/future-0.15.2.tar.gz#md5=a68eb3c90b3b76714c5ceb8c09ea3a06
Processing future-0.15.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-wpK9rC/future-0.15.2/setup.cfg
Running future-0.15.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-wpK9rC/future-0.15.2/egg-dist-tmp-CUiQaX
warning: no files found matching '*.au' under directory 'tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'tests'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
past.builtins.misc: module MAY be using inspect.stack
past.translation.__init__: module references __file__
past.translation.__init__: module references __path__
future.utils.__init__: module MAY be using inspect.stack
future.backports.test.ssl_servers: module references __file__
future.backports.test.support: module references __file__
future.standard_library.__init__: module references __file__
future.standard_library.__init__: module references __path__
Adding future 0.15.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pasteurize script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing futurize script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/future-0.15.2-py2.7.egg
Searching for zope.interface>=4.1.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/zope.interface/
Best match: zope.interface 4.1.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zope.interface/zope.interface-4.1.3.tar.gz#md5=9ae3d24c0c7415deb249dd1a132f0f79
Processing zope.interface-4.1.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-6ujKfa/zope.interface-4.1.3/setup.cfg
Running zope.interface-4.1.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-6ujKfa/zope.interface-4.1.3/egg-dist-tmp-Ly9sek
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching 'coverage.xml' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Adding zope.interface 4.1.3 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Searching for Jinja2>=2.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/Jinja2/
Best match: Jinja2 2.8
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/J/Jinja2/Jinja2-2.8.tar.gz#md5=edb51693fe22c53cee5403775c71a99e
Processing Jinja2-2.8.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-rmy8wW/Jinja2-2.8/setup.cfg
Running Jinja2-2.8/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-rmy8wW/Jinja2-2.8/egg-dist-tmp-XE01Yl
warning: no files found matching 'run-tests.py'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'custom_fixers'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'jinja2/testsuite/res'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
Adding Jinja2 2.8 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.8-py2.7.egg
Searching for twisted>=11.0.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/twisted/
Best match: Twisted 15.4.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted-15.4.0.tar.bz2#md5=5337ffb6aeeff3790981a2cd56db9655
Processing Twisted-15.4.0.tar.bz2
Writing /tmp/easy_install-vjWrMJ/Twisted-15.4.0/setup.cfg
Running Twisted-15.4.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-vjWrMJ/Twisted-15.4.0/egg-dist-tmp-q0kjDC
Adding Twisted 15.4.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installing tap2deb script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing conch script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing trial script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing cftp script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing manhole script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing tkconch script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing pyhtmlizer script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing mailmail script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing twistd script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing ckeygen script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin
Installing tap2rpm script to /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/bin

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Searching for txaio>=1.1.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/txaio/
Best match: txaio 2.0.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/txaio/txaio-2.0.4.tar.gz#md5=8049f08ae608b98f4d9c60f0c9ddf621
Processing txaio-2.0.4.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-YELo_c/txaio-2.0.4/setup.cfg
Running txaio-2.0.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-YELo_c/txaio-2.0.4/egg-dist-tmp-tAH9RE
Adding txaio 2.0.4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/txaio-2.0.4-py2.7.egg
Searching for six>=1.9.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/
Best match: six 1.10.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/six/six-1.10.0.tar.gz#md5=34eed507548117b2ab523ab14b2f8b55
Processing six-1.10.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-5ePEyv/six-1.10.0/setup.cfg
Running six-1.10.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-5ePEyv/six-1.10.0/egg-dist-tmp-JNUlRt
no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
six: module references __path__
Adding six 1.10.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
Searching for Tempita>=0.4
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/Tempita/
Best match: Tempita 0.5.3dev
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Tempita/Tempita-0.5.3dev.tar.gz#md5=365c3b4f36435e2178902d5619301140
Processing Tempita-0.5.3dev.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-mhq7re/Tempita-0.5.3dev/setup.cfg
Running Tempita-0.5.3dev/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-mhq7re/Tempita-0.5.3dev/egg-dist-tmp-gjVIc4
Adding Tempita 0.5.3dev to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Tempita-0.5.3dev-py2.7.egg
Searching for decorator
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/decorator/
Best match: decorator 4.0.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/decorator/decorator-4.0.4.tar.gz#md5=dd3a0669e1e6f09699eefa2c7fbd9756
Processing decorator-4.0.4.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-JGoW1O/decorator-4.0.4/setup.cfg
Running decorator-4.0.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-JGoW1O/decorator-4.0.4/egg-dist-tmp-Mc031N
Adding decorator 4.0.4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator-4.0.4-py2.7.egg
Searching for MarkupSafe
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/MarkupSafe/
Best match: MarkupSafe 0.23
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MarkupSafe/MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz#md5=f5ab3deee4c37cd6a922fb81e730da6e
Processing MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-i8U2nQ/MarkupSafe-0.23/setup.cfg
Running MarkupSafe-0.23/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-i8U2nQ/MarkupSafe-0.23/egg-dist-tmp-evqYEI
Adding MarkupSafe 0.23 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Finished processing dependencies for buildbot
(sandbox)~/tmp/buildbot $ buildbot create-master master
/home/chris/tmp/buildbot/sandbox/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/endpoints.py:29: DeprecationWarning: twisted.internet.interfaces.IStreamClientEndpointStringParser was deprecated in Twisted 14.0.0: This interface has been superseded by IStreamClientEndpointStringParserWithReactor.
  from twisted.internet.interfaces import (
mkdir /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/master
creating /home/chris/tmp/buildbot/master/master.cfg.sample
populating public_html/
(sandbox)~/tmp/buildbot $ mv master/master.cfg.sample master/master.cfg
(sandbox)~/tmp/buildbot $ buildbot start master
Following twistd.log until startup finished..

The buildmaster took more than 10 seconds to start, so we were unable to
confirm that it started correctly. Please 'tail twistd.log' and look for a
line that says 'BuildMaster is Running' to verify correct startup.

(sandbox)~/tmp/buildbot $ buildbot --verbose start master
2015-10-14 08:48:39-0700 [-] Log opened.
2015-10-14 08:48:39-0700 [-] Following twistd.log until startup finished..
2015-10-14 08:48:49-0700 [-] 
2015-10-14 08:48:49-0700 [-] The buildmaster took more than 10 seconds to start, so we were unable to
2015-10-14 08:48:49-0700 [-] confirm that it started correctly. Please 'tail twistd.log' and look for a
2015-10-14 08:48:49-0700 [-] line that says 'BuildMaster is Running' to verify correct startup.
2015-10-14 08:48:49-0700 [-] 
2015-10-14 08:48:49-0700 [-] Main loop terminated.
(sandbox)~/tmp/buildbot $ cat master/twistd.log 
(sandbox)~/tmp/buildbot $
```

There are a fair number of warnings in there, but nothing reports an error. The log file is empty, as shown at the end there.

I'm not sure where to begin diagnosing. The tutorial lists Python and its dev pacakges, virtualenv, and git as dependencies, so:

```
~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.6
~ $ virtualenv --version
1.11.4
~ $ git --version
git version 1.9.1
~ $ apt-cache showpkg python-dev
Package: python-dev
Versions: 
2.7.5-5ubuntu3 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
```

How do I begin diagnosing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firstrun example in the Buildbot documentation didn't work for me neither. I've tried with last [tutorial](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/tutorial/firstrun.html) from Buildbot and it works. It uses **pip** instead of **easy_install**: